# Chef: use attributes from specific resource in generic resource

Tags: chef-infra

I have a cookbook that installs several RPM packages through the use of the `package` Chef resource:

```
%w(
  nfs-utils
  autofs
  # etc.
  # etc.
  # etc.
).each do |pkg|

package pkg
```

I often have problems downloading the files from the server due to network glitches. I see that the packages are compiled as `yum_package`s:

```
Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /downloads/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb

65: package pkg
66: 

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /downloads/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:65:in `block in from_file'

yum_package("nfs-utils") do
 package_name "nfs-utils"
 action [:install]
 retries 0
 retry_delay 2
 default_guard_interpreter :default
 declared_type :package
 cookbook_name "my_cookbook"
 recipe_name "default"
 flush_cache {:before=>false, :after=>false}
end

Platform:
---------
x86_64-linux
```

I would like to use the `retries` option which is available with `yum_package`, but not available through the generic `package` resource. Is that possible? (I can't change from `package` to `yum_package` explicitly, though).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the [`package`](https://docs.chef.io/resource_package.html#properties) resource documentation, the properties `retries` and `retry_delay` exist...

**retries**:

> Ruby Type: Integer | Default Value: 0
>
> The number of attempts to catch exceptions and retry the resource.

**retry_delay**:

> Ruby Type: Integer | Default Value: 2
>
> The retry delay (in seconds).